# Visual Studio C++: Seeing the ASM code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I'd like to see all the asm produced by Visual Studio C++ to learn a bit about ASM, compilers, etc. I know with GCC, you can do it with the -S argument, but not in VS.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to start your program in the integrated debugger, then turn on the assembly language view. This shows the assembly language interleaved with your original source code.

Back when I used VS, this was Alt+F7 or something but it's probably changed. The advantage of doing this (over using `-S` equivalent) is you can focus on exactly which line(s) of code you're interested in.

Comment: BTW, this is Alt+8 in VS 2008 (at least in VC++ express).

Comment: Or right click in the source window and choose "Go To Disassembly".

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on your project and then Properties -> C/C++ -> Output files -> Assembler Output and set it to something else than No Listing. Equivalently, you can add one of the /FA switches to the compiler's command line.

Comment: The question was how to see, not how to create!

Comment: You have forgotten to say how to see this listing. In many places on SO is said how to create it, but nowhere - how to see it later.